# How to efficiently group tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking for the efficient way to group the Indexes of a tensor dataset in tensorflow 2, python.

Here follows an example of the action to perform

```
Input
------------------
id | feature_frame

 0 | [0, 1, 2, 3]
 1 | [0, 1, 2, 3]
 2 | [3, 1, 1, 2]
 3 | [7, 7, 1, 2]
 4 | [0, 1, 2, 3]
 5 | [3, 1, 1, 2]

Output
------------------
0 | [0,1,4]
1 | [2,5]
2 | [3]
```

As you can see, the indexes corresponding to equal tensors are grouped together. The order, in which they are grouped and where each group is positioned, is not relevant.

Comment: How id, feature_frame are saved? Give a code example.

Answer (score 0):

With integer values, if the number of columns and the values are not too big, you may be able to compute a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) for each feature frame, that is, a single integer that univocally represents each combination of values. Then it is quite easy to solve.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Assumes values in f are non-negative, you could shift by minimum if not
f = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2],
                 [7, 7, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=tf.int32)

# Compute hash
m = tf.reduce_max(f, axis=0)
b = tf.math.cumprod(m, exclusive=True)
h = tf.reduce_sum(f * b, axis=1)
# Find unique positions and counts
_, idx, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(h)
# Make groups
groups = tf.argsort(idx)
print(groups.numpy())
# [0 1 4 2 5 3]
# The counts array gives the size of each consecutive groups
print(counts.numpy())
# [3 2 1]
# Or you can get the array of group indices
group_idx = tf.gather(idx, groups)
print(group_idx.numpy())
# [0 0 0 1 1 2]
# Or even a ragged tensor
groups_rag = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(groups, counts)
print(groups_rag.to_list())
# [[0, 1, 4], [2, 5], [3]]
```

If you cannot use the hashing trick, you can always compare every row to each other, which is more expensive but should always work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2],
                 [7, 7, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=tf.int32)

# All to all comparison
cmp = tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(f, axis=1), f)
# Find matching rows
eq = tf.reduce_all(cmp, axis=-1)
# Unfortunately tf.math.argmax is indeterministic on ties
# so we multiply by an index array to find first match for each row
r = tf.range(tf.shape(f)[0], 0, -1)
match_idx = r * tf.dtypes.cast(eq, r.dtype)
group_id = tf.math.argmax(match_idx, axis=1)
# Continue as before
_, idx, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(group_id)
# ...
```

EDIT: Yet another alternative using strings, as proposed:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2],
                 [7, 7, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=tf.int32)

# Convert to string
fs = tf.strings.as_string(f)
# Join with some non-numerical character
h = tf.strings.reduce_join(fs, axis=1, separator=' ')
# Continue as before
_, idx, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(h)
# ...
```

EDIT: For the sake of completeness, here is yet another version using a nested loop, probably not very fast:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

f = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2],
                 [7, 7, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 2, 3],
                 [3, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=tf.int32)

n = tf.shape(f)[0]
ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=n, element_shape=())
_, ta = tf.while_loop(lambda i, ta: i < n,
                      lambda i, ta: (i + 1, ta.write(i, tf.while_loop(
                          lambda j: ~tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(f[i], f[j])),
                          lambda j: [j + 1],
                          [0])[0])),
                      [0, ta])
h = ta.stack(0)
# Continue as before
_, idx, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(h)
# ...
```

Comment: Hallo Jdehesa. Wow! You have managed to do really everything in Tensorflow!. Unfortunately the number of columns and the values are big. Is there any other way to solve the issue?

Comment: @TomLeo I added an all-to-all comparison solution that should work for all cases (unless you arrays are really huge and you run out of memory, that is).

Comment: Hello Jdehesa. Thanks a lot for your proposal. A all-to-all solution is unfortunately not efficient for high amount of rows. I was thinking a way to make something similar to your hash solution by using strings. I have seen there is the function tf.string.as_string(...). Do you think it will be still efficient? Do you have any suggestion how smartly apply it?

Comment: @TomLeo Sure, I'm not sure how fast string manipulation is going to be, but I added that implementation.

Comment: @TomLeo Just as an alternative, I added a loop-based implementation, which is probably not going to be very fast...

Comment: Hello Jdehesa, thank you for your suggestions. I have found in tensorflow also the function tf.data.experimental.group_by_reducer. Is it possible to use it for this topic? How would you implement it at best? What do you think, will it be faster than the sort based version?

Comment: @TomLeo I don't think so, `group_by_reducer` requires a `tf.int64` key for each element, so you would need something like the hash solution I first proposed, which you already said wouldn't work for you... Also, using a `Reducer` seems likely to be slower, since it would have to concatenate indices iteratively...

Comment: Thank you very much Jdehesa for your support. Actually what is really missing is a builtin function of tensorflow that can sort the rows of a matrix or dataset considering more than one column. Matlab and Panda provide that. I find strange that Tensorflow does not. Do you know how can I request to the team of tensorflow the development of such function?

Comment: @TomLeo You mean something like [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)? Yes, I don't think TF implements anything like that atm, you could [create an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) asking for that feature, you could mention the NumPy function for reference and maybe give a clear example of what could be the expected behavior, with inputs and output.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution of the same problem when I found that TF has some functions with behaviour very similar to groupby which are called segment functions and perform reduce operations such as min, max and mean: e.g. [tf.math.segment_min](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/segment_min)

As @jdehesa shows, once you get your group ids in `idx` then you can do something like:

```
tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(
    data = some_tensor,
    segment_ids = idx,
    num_segments = tf.unique(idx)[0].shape[0]
)
```

This gives you flexibility for grouping by one set of tensors by joining them as strings and getting `idx` and applying agg functions to another set of tensors.